# How do I enable autoplay for the media player component?

Tags: delphi, video, components, autoplay

I'm trying to enable autoplay for the media player component. Like, when someone opens my program, a video appears as an intro, then it automatically closes after several seconds, and then the next form appears while the first form that includes the media player closes automatically!

I'm using Delphi 10.4!

Comment: You're basically asking for how to work with [events](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Events_(Delphi)) (a key element in Delphi), especially [TForm.OnShow](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnShow) and [TMediaPlayer.OnNotify](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer.OnNotify).

Comment: @AmigoJack can you please teach me how to do that? i'm a beginner! i'm trying to learn please help!

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not for teaching basics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402345/4299358). In your case you haven't outlined what you tried so far and where you failed - if you want all the work to be done by someone else (and that's what your Q implies) expect to not get any A.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i didn't quite understand can you please explain more? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the Form's [`OnShow`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OnShow) event, start [playing](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer.Play) the media (see [Adding Audio or Video Clips to an Application](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Adding_Audio_or_Video_Clips_to_an_Application) for more details), making sure to specify [`Notify=true`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer.Notify) on the media player.

Then, in the media player's [`OnNotify`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer.OnNotify) event, [`Close()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Close) the Form, and in the Form's [`OnClose`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OnClose) event you can [`Show()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Show) the next Form.

For example:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer1.FileName := ...;
  MediaPlayer1.Open;
  MediaPlayer1.Notify := True;
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.MediaPlayer1Notify(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;
```

Just beware that if you place the `TMediaPlayer` on your `MainForm` and then `Close()` that Form, your app will exit.  So, either put the `TMediaPlayer` on a non-`MainForm` Form and show it before the `MainForm` is shown, or else `Hide()` the `MainForm` (and use the [`OnHide`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OnHide) event) instead of `Close()` it.

Comment: it runs without errors but the video didn't play! help please!

Comment: @Franklin Did it ever play with `TMediaPlayer`?

Comment: @Franklin Did you read the documentation at all? See [Adding Audio or Video Clips to an Application](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Adding_Audio_or_Video_Clips_to_an_Application) and [Example of Adding Audio or Video Clips (VCL_Only)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Example_of_Adding_Audio_or_Video_Clips_(VCL_Only))

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is my first time using tmediaplayer sir! can we talk on discord or skype so i can share my screen and show you my delphi program?  i really need help with this component asap please!

Comment: @RemyLebeau and it did not play idk what to do!

Comment: "*can we talk on discord or skype*" - no. "*so i can share my screen*" - you can edit your question to post screenshots. "*i really need help with this component asap*" - this is a Q&A site, we are not here to provide *real-time* support. If you want that, hire a freelancer.